# Slumdog millionaire (6)

Tags: knowledge, movies

My Indian friend Jamal recently participated in the well-known TV quiz
show ***[Who wants to be a millionaire?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Wants_to_Be_a_Millionaire)***. You might have heard or read about Jamal's spectacular success; the media reported on it extensively.

Here is what Jamal told us about his 2.000 Euro question:

> After the commercial break, Prem Kumar started a little friendly chat about
>   my job.  I said that I enjoyed software design because sometimes it was a
>   lot like solving puzzles.  He made some crack about me having to solve quite
>   a bit of them now, and then the lights went down again and the next question
>   came up. Prem pulled off a big show with this question, and he obviously
>   enjoyed repeating the word "2000" over and over again, since it also showed 
>   up as part of the question text.  The question seemed to be much too hard for 
>   a 2.000 Euro question.  I guess that the question makers and show producers
>   just had chosen it at this level so that Prem could play around with the words.
>
> Now about the answers, I didn't think it was a romantic comedy, so that left 
>   option A out.  I was also pretty sure D was "just" an award winning epic and 
>   certainly not on top.  Once again, however, I had to reach back into the 
>   depths of my memory to decide between the two remaining choices.  Prem made 
>   some comment that almost interrupted my concentration; I just replied 
>   "Yeah, I could do that", but without committing myself to anything.
>
> I could see an old newspaper article coming into focus in my mind and suddenly remembered that C had domestically beaten B, though not by much.  Thinking that the 50/50 option that Prem had mentioned would probably only leave me with answers B and C anyway, I decided to trust my memory instead.  Turns out, I had a good one.  At least this time.  Later I found out that answer B indeed had been the runner-up, while A and D had been farther down the list.

***What was the 2.000 Euro question?

What were the four possible answers A, B, C, D?***

Comment: Is there a way to create better titles for these puzzles?

Comment: It's pretty weird to see that people down-vote this kind of questions. In my opinion, this is a pretty good series of puzzles, with increasing difficulty, which aren't too easy to solve if you don't have a bunch of time to spend.  
I like it, keep up the good work!

PS: as Emrakul suggested, the title could be improved!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Question:

> What film grossed most in 2000?

Answers:

> A: What Women Want
>  B: Cast away
>  C: **How the Grinch stole christmas**
>  D: Gladiator

Reasons:

> A is a romantic comedy, D won the Oscar prize in 2001, C and B are the 1st and 2nd 2001 worldwide grosses, and C beat B domestically.

Comment: A question about American films on an Italian game show? Seems pretty unconventional.

Comment: What make you think it is an Italian game show?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure of the answer yet, but I will post my ideas for others.

> I'm thinking of a movies in year 2000 that were somehow significant

A:

> List of RomComs is:
>  Down to You
> Return to Me
> Keeping the Faith
> Boys and Girls
> Loser 
> Woman on Top 
> What Women Want

B:

> For B & C I need to find similar movies but C was more successful <strike>in India</strike> domestically for the studio

C:

> For B & C I need to find similar movies but C was more successful <strike>in India</strike> domestically for the studio

D:

> Award winning epic for year 2000 is **Gladiator** and **Crouching Tiger, Hidden Dragon** 
> but if it wasn't on top, I would scratch Gladiator, because that tops many leaderboards.

My concept of questions is:

> Highest grossing film perhaps with some unknown condition.

My inspiration:

> [Wiki - 2000 in Film](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_in_film)
> [Highest grossing films of 2000](http://www.boxofficemojo.com/yearly/chart/?view2=worldwide&yr=2000&sort=wwgross&order=DESC&p=.htm)